# log4j2 not writing to log file specified in xml file

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running into an issue with log4j2 on my springboot api. We're using ubuntu on an EC2 instance and can't get the log4j2.xml to create a log file where we want it to, nor write to a log file that we manually create in that location.
We've checked the xml file multiple times, and as far as we can tell the issue isn't with the file itself. We've also messed around with permissions for writability of the log file and we don't think that's the problem either; we're both super new to linux though so we could be wrong.

```
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Property name="filename">log/api.log</Property>
            <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %p %m%n</Property>
        </Properties>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="log/api.log">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>

        <RollingFile name="appLog"
            fileName="api.log"
            filePattern="application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="19500KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
         <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="appLog"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="appLog"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="appLog"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have two files specified; log/api.log and api.log. Log4j will create these in whatever the current working directory is when the application is started. Since you haven't stated where the files are actually being created not much more can be said.